# How can i check if post has been liked by currentUser

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have a put request that increments/decrements likeCount post. It fetchs the post id, and does the following

**like**

[image]

**unlike**

[image]

How could i refactor the code in a such a way, the liked is based if the current user liked it or not.

How would i check if it has been likedByMe or current user ?

**post.controller.js**

```
likePost: async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const id = req.params.id;

    const post = await models.Post.findByPk(id);

    if (post.liked === true) {
      post
        .update({
          liked: false,
          likeCounts: post.likeCounts === 0 ? 0 : --post.likeCounts
        })
        .then(unliked => {
          res.status(200).send({
            message: "You have unliked this post",
            post: unliked
          });
        });
    } else {
      post
        .update({
          liked: true,
          likeCounts: ++post.likeCounts
        })
        .then(liked => {
          res.status(200).send({
            message: "This post has been liked",
            post: liked
          });
        });
    }
  }
```

modified code will this work

```
 likePost: async (req: any, res: Response) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const userId = req.params.userId
    const post = await models.Post.findByPk(id);

    if (userId === post.authorId){
      if (post.liked === true) {
        post
          .update({
            liked: false,
            likeCounts: post.likeCounts === 0 ? 0 : --post.likeCounts
          })
          .then(unliked => {
            res.status(200).send({
              message: "You have unliked this post",
              post: unliked
            });
          });
      } else {
        post
          .update({
            liked: true,
            likeCounts: ++post.likeCounts
          })
          .then(liked => {
            res.status(200).send({
              message: "This post has been liked",
              post: liked
            });
          });
      }
     }
  }
```

Comment: You will need to store the user ids of the people who have liked the post, not just whether it's been liked at all.

Comment: so i understand that i may have to pass in a user id param, but how would i refactor the code in a such a way it checks if the current user has liked this post.

Comment: i made some updates to the post let me know if thats the right direction

Comment: Merely incrementing/decrementing a like counter discards the identity of who was doing the liking/unliking.   Keeping the "who" is usually done with a new entity that associates the liker and the thing liked. Instead of increment/decrement, you'd do a create/destroy of these SomeoneLikedSomething objects.  That's more than a code refactor.